# UICollectionView attempt to create view animation for nil view

Tags: swift

I have a `UICollectionView` with 2 `sections`. In the first one there is a custom `UISegmentedControl` with two options: "All" and "Favourite".When I click one of them, I fetch the data from my `CoreData`, so if I click "All" I fetch data from my `entity` number 1, if I click "Favourite" I fetch data from my `entity` number 2. In the second `section` I have my `UICollectionViewCell`. When I click the `UISegmentedControl`, in addition to fetch the data I want to reload the data only in the second section,where I have my cells, and not in all the collectionView. I tried to use the method `reloadSections` but I get an error: `attempt to create view animation for nil view`.I can't figure out why.This is my code for the segmentedControl:

```
func didSelect(_ segmentIndex: Int) {
    if segmentIndex == 1{
        fetchDataFavourite()
        collectionView?.reloadSections([0])
    }else{
        fetchData()
        collectionView?.reloadSections([0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in my case it was missing

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

in my implementation of `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that happens with your custom `UICollectionViewLayout` because of standard `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` avoids this issue perfectly.

In case you added supplementary elements into the calculation on `prepare()` your supplementary header and footer become mandatory.

```
    private var cache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    // MARK: -

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        cache.removeAll()
...
        for section in 0 ..< countSections {
...
            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                                              with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section))
            attributes.frame = frame
            cache.append(attributes)
...
            for item in 0 ..< countItems {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
...
                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = rect.integral
                cache.append(attributes)
...
            }
...
            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter,
                                                              with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section))
            attributes.frame = frame
            cache.append(attributes)
...
        }
    }
```

In order to make them optional - avoid adding their attributes (even empty) in the calculation.